# push notifications settings in iphone

Tags: iphone, settings, push-notification

In iphone settings there is an option called "Notifications" and inside it should be list of application which use Push Notifications.

1. How can I place my App there? Does the iphone SDK to this automatic if the appllication uses notifications or should I do this on my own?
2. If it should be automatic then why my app isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is done automatically.
2. You are doing something wrong. Please provide more information.